# Browse folders/files of another PC in the wireless LAN using the browser

Tags: browser, lan, file-sharing

I would like to browse folders of another PC in my wireless LAN using a browser (chrome, IE, firefox).

How do I need to configure the computers and the wireless LAN to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention what OS you are running, so I am going to assume it is Windows. Assuming that all of your computers are on the same network and can talk to each other, the easiest method of accomplishing the sharing of files would be to join all of the computers onto the same workgroup and setup Windows File Sharing.

Here is the link to a video that appears to walk you through the process, that might be a little more helpful than some of the steps I will detail below. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AG10HiIr9kw

Navigate to a folder that you would like to share on one computer, right click on it and click properties. Go to the sharing tab and click share; a new window should appear. Type Everyone when asked who you want to share this with, keep in mind that setting permissions this way will allow anyone else on your wireless network to access these files. You should then notice a link that says "Network Path" above the share button. IF you copy and paste this path into Windows Explorer on any other computer on the wireless network and access the shared files. The format of the network path is

*\\YourPCname\shared\folder\path.*

From windows explorer you can also click on the "Network" option on the far left panel, this will show you the names of the computers on your network, double click on any of these to see what folders they are sharing.

This should be enough to get you going and allow you to ask more specific questions to further address your needs. Let us know if you have issues with any of the above, are using a different OS, or if you were looking for something else (In which case, please provide further information)

Answer (score -2):

Google Chrome has a new in browser app that will let you do this.  Detailed instructions can be found [Here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2144562/hands-on-chrome-remote-desktop-app-for-android-makes-remote-access-easy.html)
 and [Here.](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/04/16/hands-on-with-googles-new-chrome-remote-desktop-app/)
EDIT: The remote destination (PC with folders you want to access) needs to have chrome installed.  You will go to the chrome app store and download chrome remote desktop.  It will add it to the browser and you then need to choose how you want to access this new PC.  IT will enable you to access not only files and folders, but control the PC remotely.

Comment: "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: added additional info